# Change NSDateFormatter For Dates in Array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Right now my dates look like this:`` `2011-01-01 5:45:23 +0000 ``

I want them to look like this: `2011-01-01 00:00:00 +0000` (notice how everything is 00 beside the date, month, and year).

I have an array of NSdates which is fetched from this code:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Session" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES]; //set to YES if you only want unique values of the property
[request setPropertiesToFetch :[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"timeStamp"]]; //name(s) of properties you want to fetch
NSError *error;
NSArray *objects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSArray *data = [objects valueForKey:@"timeStamp"];
NSLog(@"The content of data is%@", data);
```

I want to remove daylight savings and have 0:00:00 for the time aspect of each date, thus I need this NSDateFormatter method:

```
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]; // e.g., set for mysql date strings
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
NSString* mysqlGMTString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

So how can I combine the two to work together?

Comment: Meaning I want to apply that date formatter to the dates in the data array, then create a new array with the updated dates without daylight savings time.  Basically I want the dates to have 00:00:00 for hour, minute, and second component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your requirement is to have strings in the `data` array, this code should suit your purpose.

```
NSMutableArray * resultsArray = [NSMutableArray array];

NSCalendar * gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
[gregorian setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];

NSUInteger flags = ( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit );

NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];

[datesArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSDate * date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:[gregorian components:flags fromDate:obj]];

    [resultsArray addObject:[formatter stringFromDate:date]];
}];
```

`resultsArray` will contain the strings that you need. Now you can have `data` referring to the object

As for the search with a date part,

```
- (void)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView didSelectDate:(NSDate *)d { 
    // Assuming `data` is from the code above & the date is in `00:00:00 +0000` form.

    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];

    NSString * dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:d];

    if ( [data containsObject:dateString] ) {
        // Push object to detail view??
    }
}
```

Also use `yyyy` instead of `YYYY`. [`They are not the same`](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: Thanks Deepak, Check the method I will be using this array for here.  It will be replacing the `data` array in this method.  Can you tell me if I just need to add the first method you have, or the second printing one also? https://gist.github.com/1047301

Comment: Updated code to suit your needs. Let me know if it works or doesn't. :)

Comment: One thing though, I  have a method called `- (void)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView didSelectDate:(NSDate *)d {
 NSLog(@"calendarMonthView didSelectDate");`.  Do you know how to get the date from the array we created corresponding to the date selected from the calendar.  I can then save this as NSDate and push to detailView.

Comment: Added some code. Made some assumptions though as mentioned in the comment.

Comment: Thanks Deepak, I think that works fine, but I need to someone get the Object for which that timeStamp date is a property for.  Do you have any idea how I can go backwards with the date conversions, to find the Session objet for the date I selected?  Here is the code I used to get the date along with the fetch of the object. Thanks. https://gist.github.com/1047444

Comment: I think this should be a question of its own as it is, although related, a different problem.

Comment: Ok ill make a new question, can you help answer it then?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];

for (NSDate *d in data) {
    NSString* mysqlGMTString = [formatter stringFromDate:d];
    // ...
}

[formatter release];
```

Comment: I want an array with the dates in them, similar to the data array I had before, just without daylight savings time.